# Are constant "flags" considered good style? (c++)

Tags: c++, oop, styles, c++17

I am currently working an a library and I wonder if it's considered good style to have all-caps constants like:

```
constexpr int ONLY_LOWERCASE = 1;
constexpr int ONLY_UPPERCASE = 2;
```

And so on. I plan on using it to let the library user control the behavior of the functions like:

```
doSomeThing(var, ONLY_UPPERCASE);+
```

Thanks

Comment: using `enum` or `enum class` should be preferred.

Comment: Can you compose your flags or are they exclusive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seems like you are using integer structure to store boolean data. It might considered as a better way to use boolean structure for this purpose, for memory usage reasons.

One way of archive this target is using `enum` or `enum class` that inherit from `bool`:

```
enum class string_case : bool {
    ONLY_LOWERCASE,
    ONLY_UPPERCASE
}
```

This way you will use a single byte that indicate whatever you want, instead of 8 bytes in your example.

Usage example:

```
doSomeThing(var, string_case::ONLY_UPPERCASE);
```

### Edit

In case you have more than 2 flags, you can still use `enum` (just without inheritance from `bool`):

```
enum class string_case {
    ONLY_LOWERCASE = 1,
    ONLY_UPPERCASE = 2,
    FLAG_3 = 3,
    FLAG_4 = 4
};
```

And even so, using only 4 bytes (instead of `4(bytes) * flags_count`).
Another approach, if multiple flags can be on together (and you don't want to play with bits in your `enum` calculations), you can use a struct:

```
struct options {
    bool option_1: 1;
    bool option_2: 1;
    bool option_3: 1;
    bool option_4: 1;
};
```

And in this way you'll only use the amount of bytes that you need to store those bits.

Comment: Ah sorry i forgot to explain that I#d have about 15 of these flags.